# rename multiple files shell in Linux

Tags: linux, file, bash

I have a number of files such as file_022.bmp, file_023.bmp...file_0680.bmp. I need to rename these to something a little bit more convenient such as file_1.bmp, file_2.bmp...file_658.bmp.

Is there a bash script that I could write to do this for me? Thanks for the help and advice.

Luke H

Comment: What have you tried? You just need to know how to do some [string manipulation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename several files in the BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416263/rename-several-files-in-the-bash)

Comment: Are you saying you want to subtract 21 from "022", and remove the leading zero?

Answer (score 5):

if you're on a debian based linux system then you can use the rename script which accepts [regular expressions](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html) to rename files. Some more [info](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/150) because I find it hard to find the man page.

e.g.

```
harald@Midians_Gate:~$ ls p*.php

parse.php  pd.php  pgrep.php  preg_based.php  proc.php
```

suppose I want to change the extension to .perl and prepend the name with file_
then I use command:

```
rename -n 's/([a-z]*)\.php/file_$1.perl/' p*.php
```

would give

```
parse.php renamed as file_parse.perl
pd.php renamed as file_pd.perl
pgrep.php renamed as file_pgrep.perl
preg_based.php renamed as preg_file_based.perl
proc.php renamed as file_proc.perl
```

I select and capture the base filename `([a-z]*)` and then use it in the substitution `$1` and append `.perl` and prepend $1 with the regular string `file_`

the -n option makes it test run without changing anything

As you can see from this example your selecting regexp needs to be correctly thought out or you get cases like the above preg_based.php where you wanted file_preg_based.perl :)
to compensate for that I would've needed to use `([a-z_]*)` here

It's one of the many reasons why I keep hanging on to debian, I'd love to find the equivalent for other non-debian systems though :-/

Comment: could you show me an example?

Comment: You can have a look at this manual. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html

Comment: added an example for you

Answer (score 4):

if you have files a.bmp,b.bmp,c.bmp
and you want to end up with file_1.bmp, file_2.bmp,  file_3.bmp

using bash:

```
mkdir result
index=1
for i in *.bmp
do
  mv "$i" "result/file_"$((index++)).bmp
done
```

notes:
 using a subdirectory is advised to avoid accidentally overwriting a file that looks like file_xx.bmp

if you have too many files to fit in the command line after expansion you could use something like:

```
mkdir result
index=1
find . -name "*.bmp" | while read i
do
  echo mv "$i" "result/file_"$((index++)).bmp
done
```

after inspecting the output remove the 'echo'